# input type-text to insert in each tfoot

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table in which  with id 'filter' is used to make the textbox.

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
        <tr id="filter">
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

I wrote following code in javascript:

```
$('#example thead tr#filter th').each( function () {
    var title = $('#example thead th').eq( $(this).index() ).text();
    $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
});
```

But it is not showing textbox.Am I coding it wrong or made a mistake.I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one:

You can add jquery function `version 1.9.1` and Use `ready()` to make a function available after the document is loaded:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#example thead tr#filter th').each( function () {
            var title = $('#example thead th').eq( $(this).index() ).text();
            $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
        });
    });
</script>
```

[**Demo here**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/2hho963n/1/)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#example thead tr#filter th').each( function () {
            var title = $('#example thead th').eq( $(this).index() ).text();
            $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
        });
    });
    </script>
    
    
</head>
<body>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
        <tr id="filter">
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I added the jquery library.But its still not working.

Comment: you can see My demo @shreyagupta

Comment: Please check it now @shreyagupta

Answer (score 0):

You should include the jQuery Library.

```js
$('#example thead tr#filter th').each( function () {
      var title = $('#example thead th').eq( $(this).index() ).text();
      $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />');
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Position</th>
                        <th>Office</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                        <th>Start date</th>
                        <th>Salary</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="filter">
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Position</th>
                        <th>Office</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                        <th>Start date</th>
                        <th>Salary</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
         </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send email from outlook by inserting this link in HTML

```
<a href="mailto:[email]?subject=[subject]&body=[body]">Send Email</a>
```

Comment: What's this?? @user683016

Comment: what does you means ??